# How to examine api without documentation?

Tags: android, json, api, http-options-method

I have to use an API for my android app without any documentation. Before in my work I always had documentation, so this is a new situation for me. Backend developers said their api supports option requests. How to send option request? Using browser or what? And how to find out what I should put in POST requests' bodies? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Tell your boss to fire the backend developers and replace them with developers who will write documentation.

Comment: Yeah, seriously ^ there's no way you're going figure this out without, like, [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzing) the API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can issue an [`OPTIONS` request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) (which is an HTTP method like GET or POST) like so with, say, `curl`:

```sh
curl -X OPTIONS http://example.org -i
```

or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

However, OPTIONS is designed only to reply with the *methods* a particular endpoint accepts: *I can do GET and POST*. It would be rather irregular for it to respond with an *expected data structure*, but nothing is impossible.